# Corona will generate native code?

Tags: android, iphone, coronasdk

does corona generate native code for both iPhone and Android or it will interpret the Lua code.can anyone tell me in detail.

Comment: Could you please explain me in detail. So that it could help me out in my app development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From its [FAQ](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/frequently-asked-questions/):

> The Corona client requires an Internet connection to build because part of the build process happens on Corona Labs servers. The Lua script is precompiled into bytecode (stripping out comments, debug information, etc) before it gets sent to our server. The server embeds this data into the Corona engine, but never saves or archives it. By the end of the online build process, you will have an .app bundle or .apk file just as you would get if you had used the iOS or Android SDK yourself.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question whether it is native or not

Answer (score 0):

Part of Corona Labs' [FAQ](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/frequently-asked-questions/) states:

> "The Lua script is precompiled into bytecode"

This implies that it is **not** native code, but a somewhat optimized version of your Lua script, ready to be executed by an embedded Lua interpreter.

That said, much of the magic happens underneath the Lua script. Lua is a scripting layer on top of a C core. My guess is that for all available platforms a specific version of this core is developed. So the basis of your app is driven by native code, but your own written application logic isn't.